# Working with closures?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, closures

I have found below code from internet for closures.It basically calculates the sum for range of numbers.

```
func sum(from: Int, to: Int, f: (Int) -> (Int)) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for i in from...to {
        sum += f(i)
    }
    return sum
}
```

For calling it we write code like this

```
sum(from: 1, to: 10) { (num) -> (Int) in
return num
}
```

As in loop it is written `f(i)`.Can anyone explain me how this is working ?

Answer (score 0):

That is `trailing closure` syntax. You should google `trailing closure` to learn more about when to use `trailing closure` syntax.  As for your example above, you have  `f: (Int) -> (Int)` which is a function that receives an `Int` and returns an `Int` but written in `trailing closure syntax`.  In your example above it's acting as `identity` function.  I.e. Given `1` will return `1`, and so on.